# Plot multiple variables to compare

Tags: r, ggplot2, lubridate

what the best way to plot multiple variables while comparing different parameters for the below data

```
   df1<-data.frame(
      Year=sample(2016:2018,100,replace = T),
      Month=sample(month.abb,100,replace = T),
      category1=sample(letters[1:6],100,replace = T),
      catergory2=sample(LETTERS[8:16],100,replace = T),
      lic=sample(c("P","F","T"),100,replace = T),
      count=sample(1:1000,100,replace = T)
    )
```

I used to stacked bar plot in previous question/thread and want to achieve the above one.

```
ggplot(df1,aes(Year,count,fill=factor(lic)))
      +geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "stack")
      +facet_grid(~category1)
```

[image: presently generated but i still needed another one]

Comment: Please edit the question to make it clear what you're trying to do and what you've tried. Can you give an example of desired output?  Also: 1. Where is week in the data? 2. What would it look like to compare every week with every month? 3. What's the previous question/thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `facet_grid(~category1)` with `facet_grid(category1~Month)` might be what you're looking for:

[image]

Comment: this looks good and i have used facet_wrap but facet_grid works good for my problem